# 68000 Assembly Language - MOVE instrunction

Tags: 68000

What is the difference between `MOVE 1234,D5` and `MOVE #1234,D5`? Ive tried to look online, but cant see to find what the first instruction is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second moves the value 1234 into D5, the first moves the value at address 1234 into D5.  You might want to look into *addressing modes* (for example, here: http://alanclements.org/68kaddressingmodes3.html).

Answer (score 0):

The '#' represents a CONSTANT as [explained here](http://dev-docs.atariforge.org/files/Asm_Lang_Prog_68K_Family.pdf).

> On Page 43 it states: A constant as a source operand is specified by preceding it 
>   with the special character #